# Counting TINYINT values in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, tinyint

The table structure is like this:

```
actions: int(10)
unlock: tinyint(1)
user_id: int(20)
name: varchar(50)
```

I have such query:

```
SELECT SUM(actions) AS "sum_actions", SUM(unlock) AS "sum_unlock", user_id, name 
 FROM mytable AS `Results` WHERE user_id != 0 GROUP BY user_id 
 ORDER BY sum_actions DESC LIMIT 0,300
```

This gives `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax` error.

When I remove `SUM(unlock) AS "sum_unlock"` then query works. So I thought that it is not possible to summing TINYINTs. So I changed to `COUNT(unlock) as "count_unlock"` but this didn't help. I don't want to change "unlock" table to INT because it only has boolean values. How can I count the unlock table with summing for each user_id ?

Comment: You also need to add `name` into your `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unlock` is a reserved word.  Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(actions) AS "sum_actions", SUM(`unlock`) AS "sum_unlock", user_id, name 
FROM mytable AS `Results`
WHERE user_id != 0
GROUP BY user_id 
ORDER BY sum_actions DESC
LIMIT 0,300
```

[Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-5.html) is a list of reserved words.

Comment: That worked thank you. But it worked like this: SUM('unlock') When I changed it to SUM("unlock") it didn't work. What is the difference between *"* and *`* for SQL queries.

Comment: @trante . . . For some reason, MySQL allows double quotes for string literals.  Most databases only allow singla quotes and double quotes play the role of back quotes in MySQL.  That's just the way it is designed, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `SUM(CAST(unlock AS INT))` to count as if the column was an `INT` column without actually changing it to be an `INT` column:

```
SELECT
    SUM(actions) AS "sum_actions",
    SUM(CAST(unlock AS INT)) AS "sum_unlock",
    user_id,
    name 
FROM
    mytable AS `Results`
WHERE
    user_id != 0
GROUP BY
    user_id,
    name
ORDER BY
    sum_actions DESC
LIMIT 0,300
```

Comment: I still get `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax` error.